# How to write the data in excel file using pandas excel writer?

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas, writer

I have some code which gives output through several for loops in the form of multiple lists and I want to write the output in excel or csv file using pandas excel writer.

```
from pulp import *
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd
import numbers
from pulp import solvers
import xlwt

P=[4.645885257, 4.481959238,    4.160581972,    2.893299763,    2.746552049,    2.762327167,    2.785312466,    2.782704044,\
2.761575576,    2.790301008,    2.826271593,    2.98196142, 3.106517237,    3.049694785,    2.841111886,    2.469119048,\
2.424998603,    2.482937879,    2.541880038,    2.544940077,    2.526766508,    2.539441678,    2.60810043, 2.782490319]
X=[-50, -40, -30, -20, -10, 0, 10, 20, 30, 40]
S=[0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150]

x=10
s=16
n=24

F=[[0 for j in range(x)] for i in range(s)]


def xyz():
    Fbar=list()
    Xbar=list() 
    Mega=[22,21,20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
    for k in Mega:
        for f in F:
            try:
                FFF=max([x for x in f if isinstance(x, numbers.Number)])
                XXX=X[f.index(max([x for x in f if isinstance(x, numbers.Number)]))]
                Fbar.append(FFF)
                Xbar.append(XXX)
            except ValueError:
                FFF="NA"
                Fbar.append(FFF)
                Xbar.append(FFF)
        for i in range(s):
            for j in range(x):
                if 150>=(S[i]+X[j])>=S[Xbar.index(max([x for x in Xbar if isinstance(x, numbers.Number)]))]:
                    FFFFF=(S[i]+X[j])/10
                    F[i][j]=-X[j]*P[k]+Fbar[int(FFFFF)]
                if 150<(S[i]+X[j])<S[Xbar.index(max([x for x in Xbar if isinstance(x, numbers.Number)]))]:
                    F[i][j]="NA"


        Xbar=list()
        for f in F:
            try:
                FFF=max([x for x in f if isinstance(x, numbers.Number)])
                XXX=X[f.index(max([x for x in f if isinstance(x, numbers.Number)]))]
                Fbar.append(FFF)
                Xbar.append(XXX)
            except ValueError:
                FFF="NA"
                Fbar.append(FFF)
                Xbar.append(FFF)
        print(Xbar)

        df= pd.DataFrame(Xbar)
        writer= pd.ExcelWriter('C:\Fourth Term @ Dal\Project\Directive studies\output.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startcol=0, startrow=1, header=False, index=True)
        workbook= writer.book
        writer.save() 

xyz()
```

This is how print output look like:

```
[-50, -10, -20, -30, -40, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50]
[40, 40, 30, 20, 10, -50, -10, -20, -30, -40, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50]
[40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 30, 20, 10, 0, -10, -20, -30, -40, -50]
[0, -10, -20, -30, -40, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50]
[40, 40, 30, 20, 10, 0, -10, -20, -30, -40, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50]
[40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 30, 20, 10, 0]
[40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 30, 20, 10, 0]
[40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 30, 20, 10, 0, -10, -20, -30, -40]
[0, -10, -20, -30, -40, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50]
[0, -10, -20, -30, -40, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50]
[0, -10, -20, -30, -40, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50]
[40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 30, 20, 10, 0, -10, -20, -30, -40, -50]
[40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 30, 20, 10, 0]
[40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 30, 20, 10, 0]
[40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 30, 20, 10, 0]
[40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 30, 20, 10, 0, -10, -20, -30, -40]
[40, 40, 40, 40, 30, 20, 10, 0, -10, -20, -30, -40, -50, -50, -50, -50]
[40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 30, 20, 10, 0]
[40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 30, 20, 10, 0]
[0, -10, -20, -30, -40, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50]
[0, -10, -20, -30, -40, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50]
[0, -10, -20, -30, -40, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50]
```

And this is what I got in excel (output.xlsx):

```
0   0
1   -10
2   -20
3   -30
4   -40
5   -50
6   -50
7   -50
8   -50
9   -50
10  -50
11  -50
12  -50
13  -50
14  -50
15  -50
```

I just got the last list out of several lists from the print output copied in the excel file but what I want is the complete output (Xbar in above code) to be copied in the excel file. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't been able to reproduce the same output on my computer. But here isn't the question.

The reason why you only have the last row is that you're writing the `csv` file in the `for` loop. So you only get the last row because you overwrite all of them each time.

On solution (I think the simplest here), is to save your results over each iteration in a results dataframe (here `output_df`) and then export this dataframe in a `csv` file.
In the code below, I save the results of each `mega` loop as a new column of `output_df`.

Here the code:

```
from pulp import *
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd
import numbers
from pulp import solvers
import xlwt

P = [4.645885257, 4.481959238,    4.160581972,    2.893299763,    2.746552049,    2.762327167,    2.785312466,    2.782704044,
     2.761575576,    2.790301008,    2.826271593,    2.98196142, 3.106517237,    3.049694785,    2.841111886,    2.469119048,
     2.424998603,    2.482937879,    2.541880038,    2.544940077,    2.526766508,    2.539441678,    2.60810043, 2.782490319]
X = [-50, -40, -30, -20, -10, 0, 10, 20, 30, 40]
S = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150]

x = 10
s = 16
n = 24

F = [[0 for j in range(x)] for i in range(s)]


def xyz():
    Fbar = list()
    Xbar = list()
    Mega = [22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14,
            13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

    df_output = pd.DataFrame()

    for count, k in enumerate(Mega):
        for f in F:
            try:
                FFF = max([x for x in f if isinstance(x, numbers.Number)])
                XXX = X[f.index(
                    max([x for x in f if isinstance(x, numbers.Number)]))]
                Fbar.append(FFF)
                Xbar.append(XXX)
            except ValueError:
                FFF = "NA"
                Fbar.append(FFF)
                Xbar.append(FFF)
        for i in range(s):
            for j in range(x):
                if 150 >= (S[i]+X[j]) >= S[Xbar.index(max([x for x in Xbar if isinstance(x, numbers.Number)]))]:
                    FFFFF = (S[i]+X[j])/10
                    F[i][j] = -X[j]*P[k]+Fbar[int(FFFFF)]
                if 150 < (S[i]+X[j]) < S[Xbar.index(max([x for x in Xbar if isinstance(x, numbers.Number)]))]:
                    F[i][j] = "NA"

        Xbar = list()
        for f in F:
            try:
                FFF = max([x for x in f if isinstance(x, numbers.Number)])
                XXX = X[f.index(
                    max([x for x in f if isinstance(x, numbers.Number)]))]
                Fbar.append(FFF)
                Xbar.append(XXX)
            except ValueError:
                FFF = "NA"
                Fbar.append(FFF)
                Xbar.append(FFF)
        print(Xbar)

        df_output["Mega_{0}".format(k)] = Xbar

    print(df_output)
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    df_output.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startcol=0, header=True, index=True)
    writer.save()

xyz()
```

Output printed:

```
#     Mega_22  Mega_21  Mega_20  Mega_19  Mega_18  Mega_17  Mega_16  ...  Mega_7  Mega_6  Mega_5  Mega_4  Mega_3  Mega_2  Mega_1
# 0       -50      -50      -50      -50      -50      -50      -50  ...     -50     -50     -50     -50     -50     -50     -50
# 1       -10      -10      -10      -10      -10      -10      -10  ...     -10     -10     -10     -10     -10     -10     -10
# 2       -20      -20      -20      -20      -20      -20      -20  ...     -20     -20     -20     -20     -20     -20     -20
# 3       -30      -30      -30      -30      -30      -30      -30  ...     -30     -30     -30     -30     -30     -20     -20
# 4       -40      -40      -40      -40      -40      -40      -40  ...     -40     -40     -40     -40     -40     -30     -30
# 5       -50      -50      -50      -50      -50      -50      -50  ...     -50     -50     -50     -50     -50     -40     -40
# 6       -50      -50      -50      -50      -50      -50      -50  ...     -50     -50     -50     -50     -50     -50     -50
# 7       -50      -50      -50      -50      -50      -50      -50  ...     -50     -50     -50     -50     -50     -50     -50
# 8       -50      -50      -50      -50      -50      -50      -50  ...     -50     -50     -50     -50     -50     -50     -50
# 9       -50      -50      -50      -50      -50      -50      -50  ...     -50     -50     -50     -50     -50     -50     -50
# 10      -50      -50      -50      -50      -50      -50      -50  ...     -50     -50     -50     -50     -50     -50     -50
# 11      -50      -50      -50      -50      -50      -50      -50  ...     -50     -50     -50     -50     -50     -50     -50
# 12      -50      -50      -50      -50      -50      -50      -50  ...     -50     -50     -50     -50     -50     -50     -50
# 13      -50      -50      -50      -50      -50      -50      -50  ...     -50     -50     -50     -50     -50     -50     -50
# 14      -50      -50      -50      -50      -50      -50      -50  ...     -50     -50     -50     -50     -50     -50     -50
# 15      -50      -50      -50      -50      -50      -50      -50  ...     -50     -50     -50     -50     -50     -50     -50

# [16 rows x 22 columns]
```

The `csv` file:
[image]